# Lucene.NET can't find some words when searching?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

[Lucene.NET](http://lucene.net/) can't find some words when searching?
for example "on"

Below is a search for Lucene using the StandardAnalyzer.
Name of the field to search "LcnKey"

LcnKeys = "on lining brake sv"

Let's split the search clause to create a `string[]`

if keyword="linin brak" it will return the result.
if keyword="linin brak on" it does not return the result.

```
var searchTerms = keyword.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

BooleanQuery lcnKeyQuery = new BooleanQuery();

foreach (var lcnKey in searchTerms)
{
    if (lcnKey.Length <= 3)
        lcnKeyQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("LcnKeys", $"{lcnKey}")), Occur.MUST);
    else
        lcnKeyQuery.Add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("LcnKeys", $"*{lcnKey}*")), Occur.MUST);
}

var scoreDocs = indexSearcher.Search(lcnKeyQuery, 1000).ScoreDocs;
```

`lcnKeyQuery={(+LcnKeys:on+LcnKeys:*brak* +LcnKeys:*linin*)}`  => this query does not find the relevant row
`lcnKeyQuery={(+LcnKeys:sv+LcnKeys:*brak* +LcnKeys:*linin*)}`  => this query finds the relevant row

Comment: Was "on" in the Index? For example if you have a StopWord Filter running while indexing i'm pretty sure "on" like almost all short words <= 3 are removed and not indexed.

Comment: There is no stopword. Also indexing 'LcnKeys = "on lining brake sv"'

Comment: I would still suspect that its not in the index. You might want to use a tool to look into the index directly. In the past there was something called "Luke" to directly open the Lucene Filesystem for inspection.

Comment: I'm sure it's in the directory because I can see it when I fetch the LcnKeys. But I'm not sure "on" is in the english stopwords list. Any information on this?

Comment: Presumably these https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/51cc7418adf9da96cd37dd64ff5085d752a54074/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/Core/StopAnalyzer.cs#L52

Comment: Thanks @Ralf 
var defaultStopWords = StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET;

{[but, be, with, such, then, for, no, will, not, are, and, their, if, this, on, into, a, or, there, in, that, they, was, is, it, an, the, as, at, these, by, to, of]}